# How to define custom frame environment with fragile option?

Tags: beamer, environments

I am trying to create custom frame environment for examples. The environment modifies the header and footer of the document, but this is not shown in my example because it is irrelevant. What I am trying to do is to get custom frame environment with `fragile` option enabled, but it does not seem to work

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{
    style=Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\mlttfamily\footnotesize,
    literate=
    *{.\\}{{\textcolor{IndianRed1}{.\textbackslash{}}}}{2} % .\
}

\lstset{style=matlab}

\newenvironment{frameexamplebasmah}{%
    \begin{frame}
    }{
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile, environment=frame, allowframebreaks=0.99]

\lstinline|.\|
    
\end{frame}

%\begin{frameexamplebasmah}
%   
%\lstinline|.\|
%   
%\end{frameexamplebasmah}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer as it seems to solve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can add an optional argument to your new environment which allow you to pass the `fragile` frame option to the frame.
- in contrast to normal frames, where `environment=frame` is not necessary, you have to tell the frame in your custom environment how the environment is called.

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab}{
    style=Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\mlttfamily\footnotesize,
    literate=
    *{.\\}{{\textcolor{IndianRed1}{.\textbackslash{}}}}{2} % .\
}

\lstset{style=matlab}

\newenvironment{frameexamplebasmah}[1][]{%
    \begin{frame}[environment=frameexamplebasmah,#1]
    }{
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile, allowframebreaks=0.99]

\lstinline|.\|
    
\end{frame}

\begin{frameexamplebasmah}[fragile]
   
\lstinline|.\|
   
\end{frameexamplebasmah}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Very good answer

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh You're welcome!

Comment: Is it possible to define the environment to be fragile globally (i.e., we do not need to add `fragile` option every time we use the environment)

Comment: Not a good idea. the `fragile` option is evil - you should only use it for the frames where it is actually necessary and not by default.